# How can I write the relationship for this CPLEX constraint?

Tags: variables, set, tuples, constraints, cplex

How can I write this below constraint?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dISbQ.png)

W[i][v][t]: Quantity delivered in node i by vehicle v in time period t
UI[i][v][t]: Quantity picked up in node i by vehicle v in time period t

Product P: 1, 2
Pick up node: 1,2,3,4
Delivery node: 5,6,7,8,9,10
Time period: 1,2,3
Number of vehicle: 1,2

As I understand, for each kind of product, the quantity picked up would equal to the quantity delivered. For example:
sum quantiy in node 1,2,3,4 of product 1 must equal to sum quantity in node 5,6,7,8,9,10 of product 1

I have tried a lot of tuples but they don't work at all.Somebody could give me a hand, please.
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
range PN=1..4;
range DN=5..10;

range P=1..2;
range M=1..2;

range T=1..3;
range V=1..4;
range WW=1..2;

tuple pm
{
  int p;
  int m;
}

pm pms[PN]=[<1,1>,<1,2>,<2,1>,<2,2>];

dvar float U[T][PN][V];
dvar float+ QT[T][P][M][WW]; 
dvar float+ W[DN][V][T];
subject to
{
  forall(i in PN,t in T)
    sum(v in V) U[t][i][v]==sum(w in WW)QT[t][pms[i].p][pms[i].m][w];
    
  forall(v in V,t in T)
    sum(i in PN) U[t][i][v]==sum(i in DN) W[i][v][t];
}
```

works

At https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/low-barrier-entry-optimization-through-cplex-alex-fleischer/ I gathered many links for learning more about cplex